# How to fetch a href link under p using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get a pointer link to another article from parent webpages. The code below shows what the website looks like. All the pointer webpages start with `http://lenta.ru/`.

So my code tries to find that href element from the source html code.

However it doesn't print the pointer link which is at the bottom of the article.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

tmp = "https://uynaa.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9%d0%b3-%d1%8f%d0%b0%d0%b6-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%80%d2%af%d2%af%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8d%d0%bd-%d0%b1%d1%8d/"
html = urlopen(tmp).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if "lenta.ru" in a:
        print(a)
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `a` isn't a string; it's of type `bs4.element.Tag`. If you want to look for text in the `href` attribute, you can write:

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if "lenta.ru" in a.get('href', ''):
        print(a)
```

This will return, for the link you've given:

```
<a href="http://lenta.ru/articles/2011/05/02/lamort/">http://lenta.ru/articles/2011/05/02/lamort/</a>
<a href="http://lenta.ru/articles/2011/05/02/lamort/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">lenta.ru/articles/2011/05…</a>
<a href="http://lenta.ru/articles/2013/10/03/mourning/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">lenta.ru/articles/2013/10…</a>
<a href="http://lenta.ru/articles/2013/09/30/freezone/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">lenta.ru/articles/2013/09…</a>
<a href="http://lenta.ru/articles/2012/08/21/terranova/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">lenta.ru/articles/2012/08…</a>
```

If you wanted to further restrict your results, you could limit your search to the `div` element with class `entry`:

```
for a in soup.select('div.entry a'):
    if "lenta.ru" in a.get('href', ''):
        print(a)
```

This would output:

```
<a href="http://lenta.ru/articles/2011/05/02/lamort/">http://lenta.ru/articles/2011/05/02/lamort/</a>
```